# How i can change the format coming from backend Angular REST API?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I am using the following code:

```
this.elService.getOne(id)
  .subscribe((result: ModelName) => {
 let test = this.datePipe.transform(result['birthDate'], 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  result['birthDate']= test
  console.log(result['birthDate'])
  this.parentForm.patchValue(result)})
```

I want to change the format of the date but it gives me an error saying that ** result['birthDate']** is a String is not assignable to date, so i changed it to ** result['birthDate']= new Date(test)** but it returns an invalid date
NB: I am using DatePicker.
any Help ?

Comment: This is a javascript issue. You parse a date from a string using Date.parse("string date") not as an argument to the date constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, do you have any suggestions how i can change the format ? i tries the library moment as well but i still have the same issue

Comment: What format is it in and what format does it need to be?

Comment: it is like this 'yyyy-mm-dd' and i want to transform it to 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Comment: Just console.log(result['birthDate']) before datePipe.transform so we can see the actual string you are getting from elService. datePipe simply fails to recognize the date in the string provided by elService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use extra test variable, you can directly assign updated date to result['birthDate']

```
result['birthDate'] = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(result['birthDate']), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```